# WPALLIMPORT Exporting images from repeater field

Tags: images, urls, export

I am getting this ouput when I export the custom field image,

```
s:267:"a:9:{s:10:"sm-field-0";s:4:"1228";s:10:"sm-field-1";s:4:"1229";s:10:"sm-field-2";s:4:"1230";s:10:"sm-field-3";s:4:"1231";s:10:"sm-field-4";s:4:"1232";s:10:"sm-field-5";s:4:"1233";s:10:"sm-field-6";s:4:"1234";s:10:"sm-field-7";s:4:"1235";s:10:"sm-field-8";s:4:"1236";}";
```

I can add a function or php to covert this to URLS? but I have no idea.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a serialized string, actually it's a serialized string of a serialized string, which is very odd.  You need to convert it to an array and then get the image URLs from the IDs that it is returning.

Lets say `$str` is the variable that contains that string, here's how you would get the image URLs from those attachment IDs.  FYI I put the second `unserialize` call inside an if statement so it won't break if your value ever becomes just a single serialized string

```
function parseUrlsFromSerializedIds($str) {
    $arr = unserialize($str);
    if (is_serialized($arr)) {
        $arr = unserialize($arr);
    }
    $results = [];
    foreach ($arr as $imageID) {
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url($imageID);
        $results[] = $url;
    }
    return implode(',', $results);

}
```

Inside that `foreach` you'll want to do something with the URL.  I'm not sure what format you're trying to return them all in so I left it alone.

Comment: Hi thanks, but it is only returning one image instead, there can be mulipe images per car.

I am creating a csv file to grab export images for a car dealership, I need the images url to output all images per car item and comma seperated. 

[link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiYm8P4i3XOvh_IjA2Uu3MC3LT8ekg)

Hopefully you can help more :)

Comment: that's the " I'm not sure what format you're trying to return them all in so I left it alone" part. I'll  update the answer to get you the urls as a comma separated string

Comment: Your brilliant. Thankyou very much